# JDA Bot not detecting when user joins server

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm creating a simple Discord Bot with JDA to detect when a user joins a server, and then send an embed welcoming them. For some reason though, it isn't detecting the entire join event, even though I've used an override and have added the listener in the main class. Here is my code:
The main class:

```
public class TerraBot {
    public static JDA jda;
    public static String prefix = "t";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, LoginException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner tk = new Scanner(new File("token.txt"));
        String token = tk.nextLine();
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build();
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE);
        jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.watching("thelp"));
        jda.addEventListener(new EmbedCommands());
        jda.addEventListener(new Commands());
        jda.addEventListener(new WelcomeCommands());
    }

}
```

The WelcomeCommands class:

```
public class WelcomeCommands extends ListenerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Got join");
        Embeds.welcomeEmbed(event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("834443815205077032"), event.getUser(), event.getGuild());
    }
}
```

It is not printing anything in console, and I've also made sure it has the intents checked in the developer portal, and even gave it admin.

Comment: You also need to enable the intents in your JDABuilder.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks!